# touchesBegan not responding in my code

Tags: swift, touchesbegan

```
//
//  CommentViewController.swift
//  Bordy
//
//  Created by Micheal Tyler on 9/22/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Bordy,LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
class CommentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var constraintToBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let postId = "-KuXb-8C5kijYNqOOihB"
    var comments = [Comment]()
    var users = [Users]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 77
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        empty()
        handleTextField()
        loadComments()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
```

/* This is where I have the code placed, when I tap on the screen in the simulator nothing is printed, my keyboard also doesnt hide if a user clicks on the screen to exit the textField. */

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        print("12121")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a table view here, it's very likely that your table view's scroll view absorbs the touches before your view can get them.

If you want to hide the keyboard whenever the user taps on your table view, you may consider doing this with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead :

```
 // MARK: LifeCycle

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleHideKeyboard)))
 }

 // MARK: User Interaction

 func handleHideKeyboard() {
    commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
 }
```

Note that you can use `resignFirstResponder()` method to hide your keyboard:

**resignFirstResponder()**

> Notifies this object that it has been asked to relinquish its status
>   as first responder in its window.